# Можно ли поставить XCode 6 без аккаунта разработчика?

Tags: xcode, swift

Живу с аккаунтом университетского разработчика, не могу скачивать бетки.
Интересно поиграться с Swift

Comment: Можно. Скачать тока надо, как-то, из области доступной тока разработчикам.

Answer (score 1):

На популярных торентах посмотрите, там есть. Только версия OS X должна быть не ниже 10.9.3